# wsf.CountIfs Array Debacle - VBA Excel

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm facing a bit of a strange problem that I can't quite explain.

I'm using Worksheet function along with the CountIfs formula, and I also use Sumproduct in order to use Arrays.

However, everytime I try using 2 different variables defined as arrays I get incorrect results.

Let me explain,

when I use:

```
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim wsf
lastrow = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
Set wsf = Application.WorksheetFunction
Doctors = Array("Peter","Sam","Henry")
Emergency = Array("Y","N")

a1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(wsf.CountIfs(Sheet2.Range("P2:P" & lastrow), Doctors, Sheet2.Range("M2:M" & lastrow), Emergency))
```

I get wrong result for the a1.

However when I try:

```
a1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(wsf.CountIfs(Sheet2.Range("P2:P" & lastrow), Doctors, Sheet2.Range("M2:M" & lastrow), "Y"))

b1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(wsf.CountIfs(Sheet2.Range("P2:P" & lastrow), Doctors, Sheet2.Range("M2:M" & lastrow), "N"))

Final = a1 + b1
```

Or

```
a1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(wsf.CountIfs(Sheet2.Range("P2:P" & lastrow), "Peter", Sheet2.Range("M2:M" & lastrow), Emergency))

b1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(wsf.CountIfs(Sheet2.Range("P2:P" & lastrow), "Sam", Sheet2.Range("M2:M" & lastrow), Emergency))

c1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(wsf.CountIfs(Sheet2.Range("P2:P" & lastrow), "Henry", Sheet2.Range("M2:M" & lastrow), Emergency))

Final = a1 + b1 + c1
```

I get the correct results for Final.

Is there any way to get the first formula to work, or does vba simply not allow multiple variables that are arrays to be used as criteria in a single countifs function.

I thought that maybe I should declare the Doctors and Emergency variables but no luck so far.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You say you get the wrong result for the first one, rather than an error?  Are you sure the other two split approaches are not double counting something?

Comment: @Orbling It's not an error, but rather a very low count. The first formula shows the answers as 13, while the correct answer is 159 as produced by the other 2 formulas (I know it's correct cause I checked it by filtering the data). I don't think I'm double counting cause a1 counts the Doctors with "Y" and then b1 counts the Doctors with "N".

Comment: @TimWilliams I would extremely appreciate if you could weigh in and suggest a possible work around to use multiple arrays in a single countifs function.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula won't work unless there are equal numbers of items in the 2 criterias. (in this case you need for example Y N and Z to match the number of doctors).
I would suggest a UDF might be the easiest solution.

Comment: Thanks alot for the explanation, however since it's not possible to have equal number of items in my case, any thoughts for a workaround? And what exactly is UDF?

Comment: Barry is correct and I was wrong! (when I tested it gave the correct answer only because of the way I constructed the test data).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that having an equal number of items in `Doctors` and `Emergency` would fix the problem - if you added "Z" to emergency, for example you'd only get a count of 3 combinations, Peter/Y, Sam/N and Henry/Z not the required 3*3 = 9 combinations.

I'm better with formulas than VBA so I don't know if this is the best solution but you can **transpose** one of the arrays (whether they are equal sizes or not) and that will then give you all combinations (3*2 = 6 in your example), i.e. change to

```
a1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(wsf.CountIfs(Sheet2.Range("P2:P" & lastrow), Doctors, Sheet2.Range("M2:M" & lastrow), wsf.Transpose(Emergency)))
```

If writing this as a worksheet function you can do this:

`=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(Sheet2!P2:P100,{"Peter","Sam","Henry"},Sheet2!M2:M100,{"Y";"N"}))`

Notice that I didn't use `TRANSPOSE`, I simply used a semi-colon separator in {"Y";"N"} which effectively "transposes" it from a "row" to a "column" - I don't know if you can do that by defining the Array differently in VBA.......

Comment: Thanks a lot for the above. Seems to work fine with 2 criteria but when I try to go for a third criteria it fails again. For example it works just fine for `a1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(wsf.CountIfs(Sheet2.Range("P2:P" & lastrow), Doctors, Sheet2.Range("M2:M" & lastrow), wsf.Transpose(Emergency)))` **but fails for** `a1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(wsf.CountIfs(Sheet2.Range("P2:P" & lastrow), Doctors, Sheet2.Range("M2:M" & lastrow), wsf.Transpose(Emergency,Sheet2.Range("O2:O" & lastrow), wsf.Transpose(Profession)))` Any clues?

Comment: With 2 criteria COUNTIFS is creating a matrix of results n*m where n is the size of the first criterion and m the size of the second...but two is the limit - if you want 3 or more then for a worksheet function I would revert to SUMPRODUCT like `=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(Range1,Doctors,0))*ISNUMBER(MATCH(Range2,Emergency,0))*ISNUMBER(MATCH(Range3,Profession,0)))`....but you may find Charles' approach better

Answer (score 0):

You could use arrays in VBA instead of functions:

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
Sub MediCount()
'
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim Doctors As Variant
    Dim Emergency As Variant
    Dim Profession As Variant
    Dim vData As Variant
    Dim Ct As Long
    Dim jDoc As Long
    Dim jEmr As Long
    Dim jPro As Long
    Dim j As Long
    '
    lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
    Doctors = Array("Peter", "Sam", "Harry")
    Emergency = Array("Y", "N")
    Profession = Array("Teacher", "Accountant", "Plumber", "Artist")
    ' assume emergency in M, Profession in N, Doctors in O, start row=2
    vData = Sheet1.Range("M2").Resize(lastrow, 3).Value2
    For j = LBound(vData) To UBound(vData)
        For jDoc = LBound(Doctors) To UBound(Doctors)
            If vData(j, 3) = Doctors(jDoc) Then
                For jEmr = LBound(Emergency) To UBound(Emergency)
                    If vData(j, 1) = Emergency(jEmr) Then
                        For jPro = LBound(Profession) To UBound(Profession)
                            If vData(j, 2) = Profession(jPro) Then
                                Ct = Ct + 1
                            End If
                        Next jPro
                    End If
                Next jEmr
            End If
        Next jDoc
    Next j
    MsgBox Ct
End Sub
```

(or you could use my SpeedTools ACOUNTIFS function `=ACOUNTIFS(0,$M$2:$O$50,1,1,$H$2:$H$5,2,$I$2:$I$5,3,$G$2:$G$5)`

but thats a commercial Excel addin)