# Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct wsf.CountIfs with 4 arrays

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get an Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct wsf.CountIfs to work with 4 arrays. So far I always get incorrect results for a1 and b1 :(

This is my code:

```
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim wsf
lastrow = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
Set wsf = Application.WorksheetFunction

Doctors = Array("Peter","Sam","Henry")
Emergency = Array("Y","N")
Specialty = Array("GP","Specialist")
Rank = Array("Senior","Junior")

a1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(wsf.CountIfs(Sheet2.Range("P2:P" & lastrow), Doctors, Sheet2.Range("M2:M" & lastrow), Emergency, Sheet2.Range("O2:O" & lastrow), Specialty, Sheet2.Range("R2:R" & lastrow), Rank))

b1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(wsf.SumIfs(Sheet2.Range("G2:G" & lastrow), Sheet2.Range("P2:P" & lastrow), Doctors, Sheet2.Range("M2:M" & lastrow), Emergency, Sheet2.Range("O2:O" & lastrow), Specialty, Sheet2.Range("R2:R" & lastrow), Rank))
```

The best I've got to is using only 2 criteria through **wsf.transpose**:

```
a1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(wsf.CountIfs(Sheet2.Range("P2:P" & lastrow), Doctors, Sheet2.Range("M2:M" & lastrow), wsf.Transpose(Emergency)))
```

The same does not work on more than 2 criteria.

Any clues?

Comment: Incorrect results as in errors (i.e. "#VALUE!") or, for example, you were expecting 10 and you got 6?

Comment: Have you tried replicating your formula in the worksheet? Does it give the same wrong result?

Comment: @Jaycal I don't get an error, rather I get it a wrong value. The value I should get for a1 is 178 and for b1 it should be 19783, but using the above I get 14 and 201. So I figured that something might be not calculating correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: @SamWard I have \filtered the data manually and checked how many results I should get for the countifs given the selected criteria, but for some reason the formula is not working with 4 arrays and matching the check. Any thoughts?

Comment: As per my last comment in your question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19865953/wsf-countifs-array-debacle-vba-excel/19870304#comment29567766_19870304 you can't use more than 2 multi-item criteria with that sort of SUMPRODUCT/COUNTIFS setup - for 3 or more I suggest you look at the SUMPRODUCT version I suggested....or Charles' UDF

Comment: @SiddharthRout No one has been able to solve the above so far. What do you think? Am I'm trying something impossible?

Comment: @user1350263 You have had 2 working solutions so far: one from Barry and one from me, and have not responded to either.

Answer (score 0):

I might have got this wrong, but by reading your code, I understand you are now applying the SUMPRODUCT not to **4 arrays**, but to **1 value** (one) as the results of any COUNTIFS is a integer and not an array, **and** you only use one COUNTIFS, **and** by reading the code in vba, you only have one argument declared for the SUMPRODUCT function (adding a "," before the last bracket of "a1" will initiate the declaring statemant of the 2nd argument/array and not the 5th). And so, the 4 arrays declared in the code are used in counting the eligible no. of cells/cases not as arrays of the SUMPRODUCT function. Thus if:

a) you want to apply the SUMPRODUCT to 4 integers (??? redundant) you should use 4 COUNTIFS like below:

```
Dim CountDoctors, CountEmergency, CountSpecialty, CountRank As Integer
CountDoctors = wsf.CountIfs(Sheet2.Range("P2:P" & lastrow), Doctors)
CountEmergency = wsf.CountIfs(Sheet2.Range("M2:M" & lastrow), Emergency)
CountSpecialty = wsf.CountIfs(Sheet2.Range("O2:O" & lastrow), Specialty)
CountRank = wsf.CountIfs(Sheet2.Range("R2:R" & lastrow), Rank)
a1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(CountDoctors, CountEmergency, CountSpecialty, CountRank)
' In this case the SUMPRODUCT does nothing special and you can simply use
' a1 = CountDoctors + CountEmergency + CountSpecialty + CountRank
```

b). you want to use 4 ranges/arrays (as in using the true functionality of SUMPRODUCT) you should filter the columns P M O R with a code (can provide if needed) and then create the "eligible" sumproduct ranges/arrays based on a 5th, 6th and Xth columns in your dataset that have values as numbers (long) like in hours worked, salary paid, no. of patiences, overtime, etc.

What do you want to use the SUMPRODUCT function for? Maybe there's a workaround for the SUBPRODUCT on COUNTIFS